# express/node.js - How to pass route parameters to other files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Encountered a strange bug where if I have a route defined like so in routes/posts/index.js:

```
router.use('/:id/edit', require('./edit'));
```

Inside ./edit, I have the endpoint defined like so:

```
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), function(req, res){
```

If I hit /posts/:id/edit, I successfully hit the endpoint in ./edit, but `const id = req.params.id;` will be undefined. However, if I define the route directly in routes/posts/index.js, `req.params.id` will be defined.

What is the correct way for letting the route in ./edit 'recognize' the id parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You can merge in parent router parameters by passing `{mergeParams: true}` to [`express.Router()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.router).