# ExpressJS: Passing data into route.use

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make my routes a little more modular and wonder if it's possible to pass req.params data into routes via router.use();

app.js:

```
app.use("/members",require("../routes/Members"))
```

routes/Members.js:

```
var router = require("express").Router();
router.use("/:name/projects",require("./Projects"));
```

routes/Projects.js:

```
var router = require("express").Router();
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.params.name); // param from Members.js route
]);
```

Unfortunately, `req.params.name` isn't available in the Projects.js file.  Is there a way to pass data into the router.use function?

Comment: really confused as to what purpose this has.... since your using express everything is built into a stack and follows until a response is given..  if you are just passing variables down into the next middlewear down the chain just store it inside of res.local.variablename = req.body.variable... then call next(); and it'll pass it down then you can access it inside of the next request... hope this helps.

Comment: @AndreiM. Ultimately I'm trying to keep long routes manageable by only dealing with a small portion of the route in any file.  For example, the pattern presented above could potentially continue by having everything after `"/members/:name/projects/:projectName/task/"` delegated to Task.js, then Action-Item.js and so-on.

Comment: if you want to follow this approach then one solution to the problem can be get the path using req.path and then using regex to fetch the :name value which will be string between /members/ and .projects

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211540/express-node-js-how-to-pass-route-parameters-to-other-files/36211622

Comment: Thank you @robertklep.  Changing line 1 of Members.js above to `var router = require("express").Router({mergeParams: true});` preserves the name variable for Projects.js.